# Best method to load php include files as "Pages"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a site that contains a lot of php include lines. Each "include" contains the code for a div with an image and a lightbox.

I'd like to be able to split all of the php includes into pages but only load the files when a "Next Page" button is clicked to avoid slow loading of the page

eg

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image1.php'); ?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image2.php'); ?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image3.php'); ?>
```

--Next Page--

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image4.php'); ?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image5.php'); ?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image6.php'); ?>
```

etc...

I've looked into loading the next page via AJAX with an onclick function on the button but I can't find a usable example that wouldn't break as soon as I try to apply it to my code due to not fully understanding the JS

Is AJAX the answer to how to load a new set of PHP Include files in place of the originals?

Comment: Use a template engine. For example http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score -1):

You should generate includes dinamically for example with **for** syntax.